# MyClass obj = MyClass(); Does 'MyClass()' refer to a temporary object here?

Tags: c++, c++14, temporary

Considering the case where no copy-elision is involved (pre C++17).

From cppreference (again, suppose C++14):

> Temporary objects are created in the following situations:
>
> - binding a reference to a prvalue
> - returning a prvalue from a function
> - conversion that creates a prvalue
> - lambda expression
> - copy-initialization that requires conversion of the initializer
> - list-initialization that constructs an std::initializer_list
> - reference-initialization to a different but convertible type or to a bitfield.

All the cases except the first one seem irrelevant, the first one seems to mean C++-style reference binding (`int &&x = 5;` BTW I don't understand in such circumstance the statement that temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full-expression..., the object 5 is referring to doesn't seem to be destroyed at the end of the statement).

So, as I understood, the notion of a temporary object only includes those who are guaranteed to be stored (which is not the case in my situation due to possible elision). Am I correct? Or else what do I misunderstand here?

BTW is there any difference between `MyClass()` and `4` in `int x = 4;` (or `2 + 2` in `int x = 2 + 2;`)? Like maybe I'm incorrect and the first one DOES refer to a temporary object while the other two do not...

Comment: It's counted under the "conversion that creates a prvalue" case. (Yes, it doesn't look like a conversion, but the standard groups `T()`, `T(1)`, and `T(1,2)` together.)

Comment: @T.C. so is such thing a temporary only for `MyClass()` case then? Not for the `4` I proposed as an example? Then what's the rationale for such difference? Maybe you could create an answer?.. Considering you seem to contradict the already existing one..

Comment: Wouldn't 4 still be covered by "conversion that creates a prvalue"? In this case it is conversion from integer literal, to a prvalue integer.

Comment: @NirFriedman is there any difference between those? I thought 'integer literal' is exactly one of the cases for an integer prvalue.. Again from cppreference: _The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
a literal (except for string literal), such as 42, true or nullptr;_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++14 standard[1] says in 12.2 regarding Temporary objects ([class.temporary]):

> Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts: binding a reference to a prvalue ([...]), returning
>   a prvalue ([...]), a conversion that creates a prvalue ([...], 5.4), throwing an exception ([...]),
>   and in some initializations ([...]).

In `MyClass obj = MyClass();`, `MyClass()` is a Explicit type conversion in functional notation, so it is a temporary object because it falls under "conversion that creates a prvalue".

This does not apply for the `4` in `int x = 4;` because the rule refers to "class types" but `int` is a "fundamental type".

Additionally 8.5 Initializers ([dcl.init]) defines the semantics of non-class type initializers in clause (17.8) as

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer
>   expression. [...]

while for class types, (copy) constructors are invoked. So you need a (temporary) object to copy from for class types, but not for "other" types.

[1]: actually [N4296](https://wg21.link/n4296), but that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe you're aware, in case of _possibly converted_ from the fragment you cited, like `float x = 4;` (int to float conversion), is there a temporary object for an original int of 4? And is the result of conversion a separate object from the one 'x' refers to? Not sure how it works in that case..

Comment: There is no temporary object, because the prvalue `4` is directly converted to the prvalue `4.f`which is then assigned. So there is no need for an object of type `int`, only a value, so no temporary object has to be created. The result of the conversion is a prvalue again, it is not a object, so it can't be the same object as `4`.

Comment: May I ask where in the [N4296](https://wg21.link/n4296) says `MyClass()` is an Explicit type conversion? Did not seem to find it. (As mentioned above it just seems like a constructor rather than a conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it creates a temporary, because this is an explicit conversion creates a prvalue.

In this context `MyClass obj = MyClass();`, the `MyClass()` is *prvalue*. And from the qoute you're provided, it matches the situation *"conversion that creates a prvalue"*, So yes a temporary is created.

Actually the compiler will convert this line `MyClass obj = MyClass();` to: (assuming MyClass has non-deleted default and copy contructors)

```
MyClass _tmp{};  // (default-constructed)
MyClass obj = _tmp; // (copy-constructed)
```

The first line calls: `MyClass::MyClass(this=&_tmp)`

The second line calls: `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass const&=tmp, this=&obj)`